# Where, in the human skin, would lidocaine cream stop but lidocaine injections won't?

Tags: dermatology, injections, topical-cream-gel

In some medical procedures [lidocaine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lidocaine) is [injected](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/drugs/18014-lidocaine-injection) and in some others it is topically [administered as a cream](https://www.nhs.uk/medicines/lidocaine-for-skin/).

[Histologically speaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histology), where, in the [human skin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_skin), would lidocaine cream stop but lidocaine injections won't?
**Epidermis? Dermis? Hypodermis?**

Answer (score 3):

The depth of topical lidocaine penetration is time-dependent (for the amount of time it is on the skin).

In one study they found that with topical lidocaine placed on the skin for 90 minutes, the mean maximum depth was 5mm, and lasted ~240 minutes.

The depth of epidermis, dermis, and hypodermis vary depending on which part of the body. Could you be more specific as to which part of the body, and for how long(the cream would be on for)?

References:
-Aesthetic Surgery Journal 2015, Vol 35(8) 1007–1013© 2015 The American Society for Aesthetic Plastic Surgery, Inc. DOI: 10.1093/asj/sjv079 [www.aestheticsurgeryjournal.com](http://www.aestheticsurgeryjournal.com)

-https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2317421/

Comment: If I name any specific body part the question might be interpreted as "personal medical advice" which is just not, because it's really general, but I would personally be most interested facial areas such as the chin (as far as I know the chin is not similar to cheeks in the sense that it has much more skin than the cheeks). So I just suggest to focus on the chin.

Comment: Please feel free to edit the answer accordingly. I am here to accept and any such update would enlarge the chance for upvotes.

Comment: @freethinker Simply naming a specific area of skin you're interested in wouldn't get your question interpreted as personal medical advice. Your question is clearly general in nature and you can focus it however you wish.